# Dual Boot Menu freezes on any key press

Tags: boot, multi-boot, freeze

I have windows XP and Vista installed on my Compaq Presario laptop. When I start my laptop at dual boot menu I am not able to select window of my choice when I press key to select the window it just freezes to that screen and I have to restart the laptop by pressing the power key.

I always have to use the default set OS (Windows Vista).

Comment: So, even if you press the cursor keys (up/down arrows) to change which OS you want it freezes? Is there anything special about your keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

May be this is a problem with the boot loader.Any how , this way you can set the default OS for next boot from within Windows Vista.

> If you have more than one operating system installed on your computer, you can choose which one starts when you turn on your computer. More than one operating system installed on a computer is often called a multiboot configuration.
>
> Open System by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Maintenance, and then clicking System.
>
> Click Advanced System Settings. Administrator permission required If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
>
> Click the Advanced tab, and then, under Startup and Recovery, click Settings.
>
> Under System startup, in the Default operating system list, click the operating system that you want to use when you turn on or restart your computer.

[source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/change-the-default-operating-system-for-startup-multiboot)